# JavaScript console.log execution order?

Tags: javascript, console, execution

I have code that looks something like this:

```
function pathfind (start,end,map)
{
    this.Init = function ()
    {
       this.open_node = new Array();
       this.open_node.push(start);
       console.log(this.open_node);
       this.Loop();
    }
    this.Loop = function ()
    {
       //Some code here
    }
    this.Init();
}
```

For some reason when I push "start" to this.open_node and I log its value, I get "undefined". However, after some bug testing I realized that commenting out this.Loop(); in this.Init causes push to function properly and console.log to return [start] as it should. Can anyone explain why on earth this behavior would occur?

EDIT: I'm calling

```
pathfind({x:2,y:2},{x:24,y:24},parsemap(25,25));
```

Comment: Where's the line that calls pathfind(). What you're passing may have an impact...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My testing showed that data types didn't matter, but here you go.

Comment: what happens if you put a breakpoint just before console.log statement ?

Comment: No effect. I should have realized the Chrome console is asynchronous so wouldn't play nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After further research I found that console.log doesn't execute immediately in Chrome. Hence the outdated reports.

Answer (score 0):

Your code executes `pathfind` function that returns `undefined`(and it should be this way) but you wait for result from `this.Init` function. Should probably execute it instead of `pathfind`.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted an important line of code (this.Init();). I researched a little more, and found that console.log doesn't execute immediately, unlike alert. Go figure. :\