# Question regarding Console.log in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console.log, order-of-execution

i'm meditating about this:

console.log in chrome and firefox shows the same result, before and after sorting (the result after sorting). a quick test in the playcode.io editor shows the results as expected.
The alert method in chrome works also properly.
Does anybody know about the background of this?

Found this Thread: 
[JavaScript console.log execution order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737826/javascript-console-log-execution-order)

But i don't really get it...

```
let data = [

    {A: 100232}, 
    {A: 223434},
    {A: 233434},
    {A: 645455},
    {A: 212334},
    {A: 34343},
    {A: 743434},

];

console.log(data);
data.sort(function(a, b){return b.A - a.A}); 
console.log(data);
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: console.log in chrome shows the same output; before and after sorting. 
I would expect the first console.log to show the non-sorted data...

Comment: Because `console.log doesn't execute immediately in Chrome.` and `sort` will mutate `data` array. So the first `console.log` is executed after `data.sort`. That's why it print the sorted `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem, it is how the `console.log` works in some browsers. It is printing a link to the object, and once you open this object in the console it shows a current version of the object. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Logging_objects):

> Don't use console.log(obj), use console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))).
>
> This way you are sure you are seeing the value of obj at the moment you log it. Otherwise, many browsers provide a live view that constantly updates as values change. This may not be what you want.

To see the version of the object in the moment of console logging try this:

```
let data = [

    {A: 100232}, 
    {A: 223434},
    {A: 233434},
    {A: 645455},
    {A: 212334},
    {A: 34343},
    {A: 743434},

];

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
data.sort(function(a, b){return b.A - a.A}); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```